# application android that can make a call

Tags: android, wifi

I have software coded in pascal that handle phone contacts.When you click on a contact if u use an ip phone the phone calls the contact. 
I am trying to do an android app that can do the same but instead of using the ip phone by using wifi.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, buy this may be what your looking for. You will have to more research from here...

[SipSession.makeCall()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipSession.html#makeCall%28android.net.sip.SipProfile,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)